# Почему сбрасываются методы с кнопок при смене сцен?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть сцена меню с возможностью выбора авто, из этой сцены переходим на сцену с картой и при обратном выходе в сцену с меню те кнопки, что там имеются сбрасывают методы, повешенные на них, то есть имеем нерабочие кнопки меню выбора авто, в чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что сцены не хранят своего состояния. Каждый раз при загрузки сцены вам снова нужно её инициализировать. Другими словами подписываться на `.onClick` кнопок.

Comment: Где про это событие и про работу с ней можно почитать более подробно?

Comment: @Альберт, в документации Unity https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html